# Gate question 2016 on sequence series of functions

Tags: real-analysis

a) and c) options are clear to me, but i have doubt in b) and c) option....my approach is ...it does not converges uniformly, does it mean one of complementary subsequence will definitely not uniformly convergent? That's why I check for $f(2n)$ and $f(2n-1)$  only....am i in right direction?

[image]

Comment: What is the pointwise limit?

Comment: Zero is pointwise limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as you already noted, the pointwise limit of $f_n$ over $[0,1]$ is the constant function $f=0$.

Hint. Each $f_n$ is non negative and it has a maximum value in $[0,1]$. What is it? Does it depend on $n$? What may we conclude?

Comment: Its come out to be x=1/2n

Comment: Sir i did this, i have problem in subsequence part only

Comment: Yes, that is the point where the maximum is attained which belongs to $[0,1]$. What is the attained value?

Comment: Again. What is $f_n(1/(2n))$?  Consider a subsequence.  What is $\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_{n_k}(x)|$.

Comment: Maximum value is 2, by Mn-weistrass test it dont converge uniformly

Comment: And does a uniformly convergent subsequence exist?

Comment: Yeahh this is boubt, i only check 2n , 2n-1 's only......my question is it sufficient to check this two only

Comment: I checked these two...both not uniformly cgt

Comment: You are not getting the point... Even and odd subsequences is not the point. Given ANY subsequence $\{n_k\}_k$, what is $\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_{n_k}(x)|$?

Comment: I checked for two subsequnce and supremum is non-zero

Comment: What is this supremum? It is not sufficient to check  two subsequences. You have to check that ALL  subsequences are not uniformly convergent.

Comment: Note that if such subsequence exists then we should have that $\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_{n_k}(x)|\to 0$, but...

Comment: Ohk got it, thanks

Comment: One more thing, only by calculating two subsequnce, we got a pattren for other subsequnce too, hows other will behave

Comment: "only by calculating two subsequnce" is not sufficient to know the general pattern.

Comment: Ohk, i will check others too.